# How to edit invalid UTF-8 strings in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, mediawiki

I have some utf-8 strings in my database, they are stored as varbinary. (Generally, it's mediawiki database, but that's not important, i think). I found that some strings are not in a good shape, then i make

```sql
SELECT  log_comment, CONVERT( log_comment
USING utf8 ) AS 
COMMENT 
FROM  `logging` 
WHERE log_id = %somevalue%
```

i have output table in phpmyadmin like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| d093d09ed0a1d0a220d0a020d098d0a1d09e2fd09cd0add09a20393239342d39332e20c2abd098d0bdd184d0bed180d0bcd0b0d186d0b8d0bed0bdd0bdd0b0d18f20d182d0b5d185d0bdd0bed0bbd0bed0b3d0b8d18f2e2e2e    |NULL |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What i need is to make this string readible, or upload new string with correct data. But this is varbinary field, how can i manage data inside it?

**UPD:**
found that phpmyadmin automatically added 2e2e2e for three dots at the end of each line - they were too long to show.  Original binary data are, if somebody interested,

```
d09fd0a02035302e312e3031392d3230303020d09ed181d0bdd0bed0b2d0bdd18bd0b520d0bfd0bed0bbd0bed0b6d0b5d0bdd0b8d18f20d0b5d0b4d0b8d0bdd0bed0b920d181d0b8d181d182d0b5d0bcd18b20d0bad0bbd0b0d181d181d0b8d184d0b8d0bad0b0d186d0b8d0b820d0b820d0bad0bed0b4d0b8d180d0bed0b2d0b0d0bdd0b8d18f20d182d0b5d185d0bdd0b8d0bad0be2dd18dd0bad0bed0bdd0bed0bcd0b8d187d0b5d181d0bad0bed0b920d0b820d181d0bed186d0b8d0b0d0bbd18cd0bdd0bed0b920d0b8d0bdd184d0bed180d0bcd0b0d186d0b8d0b820d0b820d183d0bdd0b8d184d0b8d186d0b8d180d0bed0b2d0b0d0bdd0bdd18bd1
```

anyway those strings contains non-utf symbols at the line end, as it seems from

```
SELECT log_comment,CAST(log_comment AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) AS COMMENT
FROM  `logging` 
WHERE log_id = %somevalue%
```

because last symbol is � - for me it seems as black rhomb with white question in it, and last 20-30 characters are missing

Comment: what will you do with the old values? junk them or not?

Comment: Hmm.. generally, i don't need them - there are just few such spoiled strings, i just know what is supposed to be in them

Comment: why not drop the column? and create another column that suit your needs.

Comment: there are few spoiled values, about ten, but others are in good shape, there are about 6k of them... and this is mediawiki db, i can't just drop varbinary column and replace it with ordinary varchar or something

Comment: May be there is somebody who speaks binary?:)

Comment: i just tried on your data: SELECT CONVERT(x'd093d09ed0a1d0a220d0a020d098d0a1d09e2fd09cd0add09a20393239342d39332e20c2abd098d0bdd184d0bed180d0bcd0b0d186d0b8d0bed0bdd0bdd0b0d18f20d182d0b5d185d0bdd0bed0bbd0bed0b3d0b8d18f2e2e2e' USING utf8) as s;  and output is ГОСТ Р ИСО/МЭК 9294-93. «Информационная технология...

Comment: what syntax is convert(x'...)? mysql seems to not know it

Comment: The length of the text is exactly 255 bytes, which is the limit of a MySQL tinytext/tinyblob field, and also often used by programmers as the size for varchar/varbinary. It looks like your original data has been clipped. The last D1 in your original data starts a new UTF-8 character, but the second byte is missing; that's why the last character is broken in the converted text.

Comment: Damn. Varbinary(255), as you said. I think i found my answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said in Joni's comment,

> "The length of the text is exactly 255 bytes, which is the limit of a
>   MySQL tinytext/tinyblob field, and also often used by programmers as
>   the size for varchar/varbinary. It looks like your original data has
>   been clipped. The last D1 in your original data starts a new UTF-8
>   character, but the second byte is missing; that's why the last
>   character is broken in the converted text."

In the MediaWiki DB in the field [log_comment] of the table [logging] should be stored headers of pages that was altered. Some of them appeared to be longer than 255 symbols, so while being logged they were clipped. That confused me; I thought that there was kind of database error, so i should just alter those strings - add to them missing symbols. Now i see it is slightly possible, so i just can gather necessary information from other fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT log_comment,CAST(log_comment AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) AS COMMENT
FROM  `logging` 
WHERE log_id = %somevalue%
```

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some clue - now in my example second line contains some blahblahblah with � at the end. Probably they were somehow broken? Anyway, i'd appreciate any advice on editing this binaries

Comment: do you mean in the output table? can you pls put the output you are getting in the comment thread.

Comment: ПР 50.1.019-2000 Основные положения единой системы классификации и кодирования технико-экономической и социальной информации и унифицированны� that's an output, one of them

Comment: Yes, same here. but the part before � is absolutely correct in both queries.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  log_comment, 
        CONVERT(log_comment,VARCHAR(65535)) AS COMMENT 
FROM  `logging` 
WHERE log_id = %somevalue%
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(max))

Comment: Thank you, but this seemed to be the same err... May be we're using different sql languages? MySQL for me, probably you're using sql server?